# Isolation Forest Implementation

Tags: python

I implemented Isolation Forest(Liu et al. 2008), but when testing with different datasets using 5 fold cross validation, in kddcup99 dataset(around 4.5 lakh rows), I am getting maximum of 70-72% accuracy, and one kddcup99 available with 2 lakh dataset, I am getting maximum 85-87% accuracy but the author's have given AUC 1.

For satellite I am getting avg of 65% varying subssmpling size from (1 to 96) and above 70% when subsampling size is more than 500, but they have given 71%(1 to 100).

For breast cancer dataset I am getting maximum of 75% accuracy but they have given AUC 0.97.

I have implemented exactly same but don't know why this. Can someone please help me. I can share my accuracies as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you working with the same tech stack as the paper ?

Comment: why do you compare accuracy and AUC? what are your AUC results?

Comment: Yes I have been Working on the same work. How to find the actual AUC using formulas. Is always AUC would be more?

Comment: Is it not (TP+TN) / total

Comment: Are you using the same feature preprocessing?

Comment: Are you using the se hyperparameters?

Comment: Cam you reproduce results of authors if you use Scikit-learn Isolation Forest?

Comment: Yes no preprocessing required if it contains only numerical attributes.

Comment: I am doing it from scratch.

Comment: What's the criteria for finding AUC. Is it not the accuracy using TP+TN/ Total

Comment: Someone please help.